# Can't create azure bot app service for python

Tags: python, azure, bots, azure-bot-service

I wish to try to deploy one from sample azure bot (https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/python/57.teams-conversation-bot) on azure platform. I use standart tutorial https://aka.ms/azuredeployment , but face problem when try to create azure bot app service with new resource group (4 step of tutorial, `az deployment create`  command). But when I try do that:
`az deployment create --template-file "D:\py\botbuilder-samples\generators\python\app\templates\echo\{{cookiecutter.bot_name}}\deploymentTemplates\template-with-new-rg.json" --location centralus --parameters appId="XXXXXX" appSecret="XXXXXX" botId="exobot2020" botSku=F0 newAppServicePlanName="ExoServ" newWebAppName="ExoServWeb" groupName="ExoServGroup" groupLocation="East US" newAppServicePlanLocation="East US" --name "ExoBot"`

console throws that:

`{'additionalProperties': {}, 'code': 'InvalidTemplate', 'message': "Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/ExoServ' is not defined in the template. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template for usage details.'.", 'target': None, 'details': None, 'additionalInfo': [{'additionalProperties': {}, 'type': 'TemplateViolation', 'info': {'lineNumber': 0, 'linePosition': 0, 'path': ''}}]}`.

So I have to change some var in template json? or what? Case information about this action in tutorial is doesn't exist. How to really deploy local bython azure bot in azure cloud platform?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem with location.

Looks like you are trying to run the bot in central US in an App Service Plan that is in East US.

Comment: Dear @Shiraz Bhaiji , I have changed location params for app service plan. Now all is centraus / Central US. But the problem is same